# Suffix ($´) in c++ regex_replace doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [c++ regex_replace specification](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/#parameters), `$´` is supposed to specify the suffix of the match. But it doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("\\b(a )(subsequence)(.*)");
  // with flags:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$´1digit$03",std::regex_constants::format_default);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
there is $´1digit in the string
```

Instead of the suffix, it prints `$´` literally. How can I make this work?

N.B: I couldn't find this `´` character on my keyboard (copied from the [regex_replace specification page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/#parameters) from cplusplus.com)

Comment: The character following the $ might be a typo because it is absent from Stroustrup's book and also absent in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a simple apostrophe `'`:

```
std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$'1digit$03",std::regex_constants::format_default)
```

this prints:

```
    v--the unmatched part
    v           v------the $' part (note that it includes a \n)
/------\  /-------------\
there is  in the string
1digit in the string
\__________________/
           ^---- the 1digit$03 part
```

So it's most likely that whoever made that page on cpluspluc.com just made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some typographical issues with cplusplus.com. :-(

The correct charaters are

```
$`  prefix
$&  matched characters
$'  suffix
```

Here's an [alternative reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/format).